# How to prevent angular from evaluating template expressions

Tags: angularjs, xss

In my app the users can provide a description for their profiles. Problem is that I don't restrict them from giving angular-like expressions like `{{ some expression }}`. That way my app is XSS vulnerable. Is it possible to make angular leave the contents of an element as is and not evaluate them even if they have angular expressions?

Comment: angular only interpolates once.. show the markup where you bind the description to an html node? Also, this doesn't make your app XSS vulnerable, a user can always run whatever javascript they like from your site...

Comment: Ed, yeah it does if another user opens their profile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if it fits your use case, but there is the [ngNonBindable](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngNonBindable) directive:

```
<div ng-non-bindable>This is a {{profile}}</div>
```

Will simply show:

```
This is a {{profile}}
```